# JavaScript setTimeout causes a scrollTop Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a collection of divs in a document that can be **filtered** by classname, as in hiding and showing elements. The list can be filtered by clicking either a corresponding element in the list or one of the items in the top menu.

**I made [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRoZgb) to illustrate my problem.**

I call the filter function for each click event, which hide all elements, and after using `window.setTimeout()` I display the right ones like below. This is to get a delay as well as to trigger fade-in css3-animations.

```
var filter = function(el){

  if(filterClass==='all'){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('.project').show(); //show all projects
      $('#filter-all').addClass('active');
    }, 100);
  }
  else{
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('.'+filterClass).show(); //show filtered projects
      $('#back2').show();
      $('#'+elClassName).addClass('active');
    }, 100);
  }  
};
```

The problem is that when I use `window.setTimeout()` the view scrolls up to the top, even if the view is in the bottom of the page.

**Try this in the pen:**

1. Show all
2. Scroll down to the bottom so that the top of the document is not visible in the view.
3. Filter by clicking some div.

**Result:**
It gets filtered correctly, but the view always scrolls/jumps up to the top.

Why is this happening?

I expected it to stay in the same relative scroll view when possible and otherwise end up at the bottom of the scrollbar. This is to me the standard and desired behavior.

Comment: I've come across a similar issue but in my instance when clicking on a button I wanted the data to change and be brought up the the top of the view regardless of how long the list of data was that I displayed. For my issue I added a `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` event on the click. You could potentially do something similar but set it to a element on the bottom or something.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: @tcasey I see, I guess I could save the current window height when a user clicks and then set it afterwards. However, I'm afraid that will make the view jump up and down but yes, maybe. Though I would rather find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry, that is what I tried to do.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sounds valid

Comment: I can't run the code posted here in the question itself and recreate the issue, thus it is not verifiable, nor complete, and a went past minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page scrolls top because you hide elements. So there is no more downward scrollable area. If you had 1000 items and you filtered 999 and show only 1, then what would you expect? The scrollable area would be way too short.

For your case, I would remove

```
$(".project").hide()
```

And hide non-matching items only:

```
else{
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('.'+filterClass).show();
      $(".project:not(" + '.' + filterClass + ')').hide();
      $('#back2').show();
      $('#'+elClassName).addClass('active');
    }, 100);
  }
```

Not a perfect solution because there would be some scroll top. But in most cases, it would be less.

Comment: Thanks, I had to fiddle a bit but you're right. When I hide all elements, then of course the view will end up att the top. +1